# How can I use glDrawArrays() insted of glDrawElements() on FrameMarkers from Qualcomm's samples

Tags: ios, opengl-es, augmented-reality

I am trying to use the same image that I successfully shows using the ImageTargets Sample, the thing is my .h doesn't have "indices" or a constant of the type NUM_C_OBJECT_INDEX.

Now, that wouldn't be a problem normally as I would just change this like of code:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);
```

for this one:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertex);
```

where vertex = myObjectVertices. The thing is when I try to do this I get this error:

> No matching function for call to 'glDrawArrays'

unless I use:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, myObjectVertices); //so not the variable but the object itself.
```

the problem here is that since on FrameMarkers I am able to use several renders I need to be able to assign the variable so it delimits to the corresponding image but I can't figure how to get that error fixed aside from using the object itself which isn't useful. Any ideas?

My variables:

```
const GLvoid* vertices = 0;
            const GLvoid* vertex = 0;
            const GLvoid* normals = 0;
            const GLvoid* indices = 0;
            const GLvoid* texCoords = 0;
            int numIndices = 0;
```

example:

```
case 1:
                    vertices = &CobjectVertices[0];
                    normals = &CobjectNormals[0];
                    indices = &CobjectIndices[0];
                    texCoords = &CobjectTexCoords[0];
                    numIndices = NUM_C_OBJECT_INDEX;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    vertices = &myObjectVerts[0];
                    vertex = &myObjectVerts;
                    normals = &myObjectNormals[0];
                    texCoords = &myObjectTexCoords[0];
                    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is pass in the vertices using

```
glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertex ); // vertex is pointer to vertices array
```

And then call

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount); // vertexCount is the number of vertices you have in your array
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
switch (marker->getMarkerId()) {
    case 0:
        //vertices = &QobjectVertices[0];
        vertices = &1Verts[0];
        normals = 0;
        // indices = &QobjectIndices[0];
        texCoords = &1TexCoords[0];
        numIndices = NUM_1_INDEX;
        quantVertices= 1NumVerts; //Vertices do Número 1
        break;
    case 1:
        //vertices = &CobjectVertices[0];
        vertices = &2Verts[0];
        normals = 0;
        //indices = &CobjectIndices[0];
        texCoords = &2TexCoords[0];
        numIndices = NUM_2_INDEX;
        quantVertices= 2NumVerts;  //Vertices do Número 2
     break;
}
```

---

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,quantVertices);
```

Answer (score 0):

glDrawArrays third argument must have GLsizei type, so basically it is an integer. In your code vertex variable is a pointer. It will not work. Pass an integer.

Comment: I tried to cast it as `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, (const int)vertex);` but it didn't work either maybe I am doing it wrong? I am fairly new to ios =/

Comment: Casting is not a solution. Do you understand what is meaning of third argument for glDrawArrays? It is number of vertices to render. You are casting pointer, that usually contains huge value, so it will pass value that completely doesn't make sense. This has nothing to do with iOS, this is OpenGL basics.

Comment: then it's even worse as this is my first project with OpenGL but now I know what to look for exactly.

Comment: @mārtiņš-možeiko Maybe you should say "Pass the size of your vertex buffer on the 3rd parameter" instead of "Pass an integer".